# Cant pass data from ajax to java

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I need to use login_role value in UserDao.java . I tried to pass `$('#login_role').val()` to `session.setAttribute("type", type)` (so to typer variable) and get value from `UserDao.java` file. But i couldnt change `$('#login_role').val()` type to String. So i tried to pass `login_role` value by ajax to java file. But still there some problem. Maybe someone can help me on that?

#### Login.jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                //setup before functions
                var typingTimer;                //timer identifier
                var doneTypingInterval = 500;   //time in ms
                var $input = $('#login_email');

                //on keyup, start the countdown
                $input.on('keyup', function () {
                    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
                    typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
                });

                //on keydown, clear the countdown
                $input.on('keydown', function () {
                    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
                });
            });

            //user is "finished typing"
            function doneTyping() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "ajax/log_in.jsp",
                    data: {
                        email: $("#login_email").val(),
                        typer: $('#login_role').val()
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#log_in").html(data);
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                    }
                });
            }

            function loginPanel() {

                var login_email = $('#login_email').val();
                var login_password = $('#login_password').val();

                if (login_email.length === 0 && login_password.length === 0) {
                    alert('Write your email or password');
                    return false;
                } else if (login_email.length === 0) {
                    alert('Write your email.');
                    return false;
                } else if (login_password.length === 0) {
                    alert('Write your password.');
                    return false;
                } else {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "UserDao",
                        data: {
                            login_email: $("#login_email").val(),
                            login_password: $("#login_password:").val(),
                            typer: $('#typer').val()
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert("success");
                        },
                        error: function (data) {
                            alert("error");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        </script>

<form action="UserDao" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        <input type="email" name="login_email" id="login_email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" />
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        <input type="password" name="login_password" id="login_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="log_in">
                    </div><!-- log_in -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-8">
                            <div class="checkbox icheck">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me" id="remember_me"> Remember Me
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- /.col -->
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <input type="hidden" id="typer" name="typer">
                            <button name="btnLogin" onclick="loginPanel()" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Sign In</button>
                        </div><!-- /.col -->
                    </div>
                </form>
```

#### Log_in.jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        //setup before functions
        var typingTimer;                //timer identifier
        var doneTypingInterval = 500;   //time in ms
        var $input = $('#login_email');

        //on keyup, start the countdown
        $input.on('keyup', function () {
            clearTimeout(typingTimer);
            typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
        });

        //on keydown, clear the countdown
        $input.on('keydown', function () {
            clearTimeout(typingTimer);
        });
    });

    //user is "finished typing"
    function doneTyping() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/log_in.jsp",
            data: {
                email: $("#login_email").val(),
                typer: $('#login_role').val()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#log_in").html(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<%  int type = -1;
    if (!request.getParameter("email").trim().equals("")) {
        type = Dao.checkUserType(request.getParameter("email"));
        if (type >= 0) {%>
<div id="log_in">
    <% if (type == 1) { %>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <select class="form-control" name="login_role" id="login_role">
            <option value="1">Dean</option>
            <option value="0">Staff</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <% } else if (type == 2) { %>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <select class="form-control" name="login_role" id="login_role">
            <option value="2">Head of Department</option>
            <option value="1">Dean</option>
            <option value="0">Staff</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <% } else if (type == 3) { %>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <select class="form-control" name="login_role" id="login_role">
            <option value="3">Admin</option>
            <option value="2">Head of Department</option>
            <option value="1">Dean</option>
            <option value="0">Staff</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <% } else {
            session.setAttribute("typer", 0);
        }%>
</div>
<%
} else {
%>
<div id="log_in">
</div>
<%  }
} else { %>
<div id="log_in">
</div>
<%  }%>
```

#### UserDao.java

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

            if (session.getAttribute("typer") == null || "".equals(session.getAttribute("typer"))) {
                System.out.println("typer is null");
            } else {
                System.out.println(session.getAttribute("typer"));
            }

            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try `stringifying` your data. `JSON.stringify({ email: $("#login_email").val(),
                        typer: $('#login_role').val() })`

Comment: Thanks a lot it is worked ))

Comment: `if (JSON.stringify($('#login_role').val()) === "3") {
                    <% session.setAttribute("typer", 3); %>
                } else if (JSON.stringify($('#login_role').val()) === "2") {
                    <% session.setAttribute("typer", 2); %>
                } else if (JSON.stringify($('#login_role').val()) === "1") {
                    <% session.setAttribute("typer", 1); %>
                } else if (JSON.stringify($('#login_role').val()) === "0") {
                    <% session.setAttribute("typer", 0); %>
                }`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo here: `$("#login_password:")` should be `$("#login_password")` ?

Comment: Oh yup sorry. but still didnt pass typer value to java file.